# Is it possible to not receive email notifications for comments?

Tags: email, notifications

I created several blogs. Two are sites I maintain but others are sites I created for other people and I retain administration access to them just in case they need me to go and fix some page, but I don't want to receive notifications every time they have a new comment waiting for moderation.

Is there a way in WordPress that while being an administrator of a blog, to not receive the email notifications for some blogs and still get them for some other blogs?

Comment: This appears to be a **wordpress.com**-specific question, that would be better-directed to [wordpress.com support](http://en.support.wordpress.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one time work for every blog you maintain. Go to Dashboard >Settings >Discussion and see following:
E-mail me whenever:

- Anyone posts a comment
- A comment is held for moderation
- Someone likes one of my posts
- Someone follows my blog

Unmark the option at which you don't want to recieve any email notifications. All done!